# javascript game: why return init: init?

Tags: javascript

I'm following a tutorial on how to make a javascript game, but i'm stuck on the return part. Why are is there { }, and what is the init: init for? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

```
var JS_SNAKE = {};

JS_SNAKE.game = (function () {
  var ctx;
  var xPosition = 0;
  var yPosition = 0;
  var frameLength = 500; //new frame every 0.5 seconds

  function init() {
    $('body').append('<canvas id="jsSnake">');
    var $canvas = $('#jsSnake');
    $canvas.attr('width', 100);
    $canvas.attr('height', 100);
    var canvas = $canvas[0];
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    gameLoop();
  }

  function gameLoop() {
    xPosition += 2;
    yPosition += 4;
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 100, 100); //clear the canvas
    ctx.fillStyle = '#fe57a1';
    ctx.fillRect(xPosition, yPosition, 30, 50); //a moving rect
    setTimeout(gameLoop, frameLength); //do it all again
  }

  return {
    init: init
  };
})();


$(document).ready(function () {
  JS_SNAKE.game.init();
});
```

Comment: How are you stuck? What are you expecting to be returned, and what is occurring (or not occurring) instead?

Answer (score 1):

The `{}` is an [object literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Core_Language_Features#Object_Literals) in JavaScript. The statement

```
return {
    init: init
}
```

returns an object with one property. That property's key is `init` and value is whatever value the variable named `init` has (in this case, a function).

---

In case that syntax is confusing, this is equivalent and might be clearer:

```
JS_SNAKE.game = (function () {
    // snip...

    function performInitialization() {
        // snip...
    }

    // snip ...

    return {
        init: performInitialization
    };
})();
```

Comment: I mean why can't you just do return init() what's the point of using the braces? I'm confused by the syntax.

Comment: `return init()` returns whatever value is returned by invoking the `init` function. This is completely different from returning an object which contains an invocable function.

Answer (score 0):

That is something that is called a [module pattern](http://www.adequatelygood.com/2010/3/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth) - where you enclose your "class" (or represent it, if you will) with an anonymous function.

The function returns the JS object that can be used to access "class" methods and variables, but only those that are exposed (public) - such as `init`.

`{}` is object literal - it is used here to declare an empty `JS_SNAKE` object - which will serve as a namespace for the following "class" declaration.